# How do I make angular-ui-layout stay within its container if it's in an angular view?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui

The problem is that internally (see `.stretch` CSS class), angular-ui-layout uses absolute positioning. 
But that can be overridden, so it might work to just make it relative and set heigth to 100%:

```
<div style="height:100%; position: relative;">
   <div ui-layout  >...</div>
</div>
```

However, that doesn't work if it is in a directive in an angular view, it doesn't exist until it has been generated and probably can't say what 100% is at that point. Unless you hard-code `height:400px`, which isn't very flexible.

What to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I chose (actually written in typescript but for the quickie I did not use any tricks) was to:

1 . Create a resize function that subtracts all other elements:

```
var resizeNodes=function() {
    $("#nodesContainer").height($(window).height() - $("#footerDiv").height() - $("#menuDiv").height())
};
```

2 . Associate the route with a controller:

```
app.config(($routeProvider) => {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/admin', {
            templateUrl: 'views/admin.html',
            controller: "AdminCtrl"
        })
...other routes ....
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

3 . Create the controller, and in it first call the resize function on initialization, and then connect a listener to the window.resize function:

```
app.controller('AdminCtrl', ["$scope", "$timeout", function($scope, $timeout) {
    // Wait for all angular stuff to be done.
    $timeout(function () {
        // Set height initially
        resizeNodes();
        // Add a watch on window.resize callback
        $(window).resize(function(){
            resizeNodes();
        })
    });
}]);
```